# HTML href tag not redirecting to .php file

Tags: html, href

```
<li><a href="test.php">A Very Long Link Text</a></li>
```

I have the following code and when I click on it it is not redirecting to test.php, can some one help on this. It redirects to page with 500 error

Comment: <li><a href="test.php">A Very Long Link Text</a></li> This is my code I am using

Comment: so where is it redirecting to ?

Comment: have you tried with a short text? do you have tags in the text? what is happening when you click on the link?

Comment: yes, I also tried with a short text, I am trying this in my website

Comment: what is your file structure?

Comment: it is redirecting to my server host page, with 500 error

Comment: php file is in the same folder where this is present, aslo if i give test.html in plae of it, it works fine

Comment: You should edit your question with the bit about the 500 error. Can you run PHP files from that directory at all?

Comment: I think yes, but how do i test it?

Comment: test what? If you can run PHP files? Sure, take a html file, change the extension to "php", load it.

Comment: are you using xampp or wamp to deliver your php files on localhost.. or on some external server??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your html code looks like this. As `a href` needs `http://` to show the text as hyperlink.

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="http://localhost:2112/test.php">A Very Long Link Text</a>
      <a href="../test.php">A Very Long Link Text</a>
   </li> 
</ul>
```

Then it will work. See below:

- [A Very Long Link Text](http://ww.lcalhost.com:2112/test.php) 
   A Very Long Link Text

Comment: yes, my code looks like this, but it gives 500 error when I try to do this

Comment: See php is a server side language and error 500 means its problem with your webserver. Are you using any webserver or just trying to execute the php page as we do with html

Comment: internal server error 500 is thrown when there is syntax error in php code. Check for error in test.php